# How would I add properties to my view model that are not part of my model using automapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I am not sure if this is possible but here is my situation.

Say I have a model like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My View model looks like this:

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CustomViewProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I am using my ProductModel to post back to a form and I don't care or need the Custom View Property.  This mapping works fine as automapper drops the unknown properties.

What I would like to do is map my custom properties in only one direction.  i.e.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomViewProperty //???This is where I am stuck
```

What ends up happening is when I call "ToModel", automapper dumps my unknown properties and nothing comes over the wire.

Like this.

```
var product = _productService.GetProduct();
var model = product.ToModel;
model.CustomViewProperty = "Hello World"; //This doesn't go over the wire
return View(model);
```

Is this possible?  Thanks.

Comment: What is the ToModel property do exactly?

Comment: That is an extension method where I map my entity to my model. It should be product.ToModel();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ignore unmapped properties:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductModel>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomViewProperty, opt=>opt.Ignore());
```

or map them:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductModel>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomViewProperty, opt=>opt.MapFrom(product=>"Hello world"));
```

Comment: I have tried both of these approaches and automapper drops my custom property.  I believe 'Ignore' is meant to do just that.

Comment: This is correct.  Jimmy forced me to double check my ToModel extension and that is where the problem was.  Ignore works.